# Convert unix time to week day

Tags: java, android, datetime

How can I convert time from unix timestamp to week day? For example, I want to convert `1493193408` to `Wednesday`.

I tryed code above, but It always shows `Sunday`..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
Date dateFormat = new java.util.Date(1493193408);
String weekday = sdf.format(dateFormat );
```

Comment: @RobinTopper edited

Comment: (1) Be aware that the week day depends on time zone. At the Unix time given, in time zone `America/Anchorage` it is still Tuesday. (2) Even on Android you may discard the now very old classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` and use the newer classes in `java.time`. These are generally much more programmer-friendly. See [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

## Using java.time

The other Answers use the troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Time zone is crucial in determining a date, and therefore getting a day-of-week.

Get an Instant from your count of while seconds since the epoch of 1970 in UTC. Apply a time zone to get a ZonedDateTime. From there extract a DayOfWeek enumerate object. Ask that object to automatically localize to generate a string of its name.

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_493_193_408L )
        .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ))
        .getDayOfWeek()
        .getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US )
```

For Android, see the ThreeTenABP project for a back-port of most of the java.time functionality.

Comment: You should either use `Instant.ofEpochSecond()` as in [Pallavi Sonal’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43676892/5772882) or multiply by 1000. As the code stands, the result is `Sunday`.

Comment: Had never seen a number defined like `1_493_193_408` but that is quite handy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @greenapps Don't forget the `L` on the end of `1_493_193_408` to make it a numeric literal of type `long` rather than default of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to multiply it by 1000 since Java and Unix time are not the same.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
Date dateFormat = new java.util.Date(1493193408L * 1000);
String weekday = sdf.format(dateFormat );
```

Comment: If you want to use the outdated `Date` class you indeed need to multiply by 1000. You also need to take `int` overflow into account. Your code incorrectly yields Monday.

Comment: fixed. The Calendar also requires millis or a Date object to set a time. So either way he needs to convert the unix epoch time to java time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a calendar instance because it provides you methods for getting that information:

```
Date date = new Date(1493193408000L);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);

System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
System.out.println(c.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Date` constructor has the following description:

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
>   number of **milliseconds** since the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Your timestamp is in seconds, if you multiply by 1000 (to get milliseconds) you get the expected answer:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
 Date dateFormat = new java.util.Date(1493193408000L);
 System.out.println(dateFormat);
 String weekday = sdf.format(dateFormat);
 System.out.println(weekday);
```

Which prints

```
Wed Apr 26 09:56:48 CEST 2017
Wednesday
```

Answer (score 1):

dateFormatStart != dateFormat

You could also check using:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
Date dateFormat = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String weekday = sdf.format(dateFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is right code for you:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
Date dateFormat = new java.util.Date(1493193408 * 1000);
String weekday = sdf.format(dateFormat );
```

There is documentation for [Java date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: This is not the exactly right code. The result on my computer (Danish locale) is `mandag`, which is Danish for Monday. The desired result was Wednesday. Your problem is `int` overflow: the result of your multiplication is `-1455211008`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with the new JDK 8 date time classes. Local date and time is calculated using the seconds from Unix Epoch and then it can be formatted with a specific pattern. The conversion to date time takes into account the Zone as well, I have used the default Zone, but it can be modified to use a specific zone.

```
ZonedDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1493193408), ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE")));
```

Comment: LocalDateTime is the wrong class here as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So you may not get the correct day-of-week as expected by the user. ZonedDateTime is the correct way to go.

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque for pointing that out. Updated the code.

Comment: Ah, `ofEpochSecond()`. I was about to forget about that one. Obviously the right method to use here.

Answer (score 0):

It’s been said already: your problem is your are feeding number *seconds* since the Unix epoch into a `Date` when it expects the number of *milliseconds* (then one would have expected multiplying by 1000 to be simple, but a couple of the other answers got that part wrong).

If you are going to work with dates, times or weekdays in your app, I agree with the answers that recommend that you consider the newer classes in `java.time`. They are much nicer to work with. Your code will more directly express your intent.

But if you only need the weekday, a dependency on a third party library may be overkill. I still recommend keeping a distance to the oldfashioned classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`, though. Is there a third option? There certainly is! A simple oneliner, even:

```
    String weekday = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%tA", 1493193408 * 1000L);
```

This yields `Wednesday` as desired. You must still be aware that the result depends on your computer’s time zone setting, though.