# Convert Integers into Date format like name of the 'Day' and name of the 'Month' in Java or Android

Tags: java, android, date, time, calendar

I have this:

```
integeres = "1495022669";
```

**I want the output:**

> "May 17"

How can I achieve it? I tried several answers on internet but couldn't get success.

**Edited**

i tried this code

```
level = 1495023057;

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Karachi" );
                            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( level, timeZone );
                            int dayOfWeekNumber = dateTime.getDayOfWeek(); // ISO 8601 standard says Monday is 1.
                            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEEE" ).withLocale( java.util.Locale.ENGLISH );
                            String dayOfWeekName = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

it gives me sunday .... but in my timezone it is wednesday. so i am stuck here , its i think joda time library that is why i am having wrong day name.

kindly help with suiteable answers.

**Edited 2**

solution

```
String dateAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM")
                                    .format(new Date(level * 1000L));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17433005/6756514

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477714/converting-integer-time-stamp-into-java-date

Comment: You say you have tried several things so you should post that code here and explain specifically what did not work about each one. Then you might be able to ask a question which is not just asking us to write code for you.

Comment: where and how'd you get your integer value? Is it valid integer/long value?  Generally integer/long values tells time in millis?

Comment: Getting it from server api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix epoch time to Java Date object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object). And/or of [Convert unix time to week day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676183/convert-unix-time-to-week-day).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is

```
    ZoneId timeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateAsText = Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long.parseLong(integeres))
            .atZone(timeZone)
            .format(formatter);
```

This produces

```
Wednesday, 17 May
```

I understand that you are using Joda-Time in the question, and if you are happy with that, you may not want to change. For new code I recommend JSR-310, so this is what I am using above. The [Joda-Time homepage](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) says “Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).” For Android this means [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

You may also want to start your transistion to JSR-310 now; I am told that Joda-Time and ThreeTenABP can coexist happily. You need to watch your imports, though, since some of the classes have the same name in both libraries.

Answer (score -1):

### Below code will provide your desired output

```
import android.text.format.DateUtils;

public String getDate(long timestamp) {
        long Yesterday = new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        timestamp = timestamp * 1000;
        if (DateUtils.isToday(timestamp)) {
            return "Today";
        } else if (DateUtils.formatDateTime(MainActivity.this, Yesterday, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR).equalsIgnoreCase(DateUtils.formatDateTime(MainActivity.this, timestamp, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR))) {
            return "Yesterday";
        } else {
            return DateUtils.formatDateTime(ChattingScreenActivity.this, timestamp, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR);
        }
}
```

**Edited 2**

I solved it by using this :

```
String dateAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM")
                                    .format(new Date(level * 1000L));
```

Comment: If you are over smart than keep quit understand. Just do your work no need your answer . If you not able to help some one atlist do not -1 answer.